# Printer location not displayed in common print dialog

Tags: java, swing, printing

I am using a printDialog with DialogTypeSelection.COMMON attribute. Refer sample code below.
Printer location is not displayed in the resulting print dialog. Is there any method to get this option visible in this type of print dialog.
Note: this option is available in DialogTypeSelection.NATIVE dialog. I cannot move to this type due to some specific requirements of the the application.

Thanks in advance
[common print dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvmS8.png)
[native print dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM38F.png)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.DialogTypeSelection;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class HelloWorldPrinter implements Printable, ActionListener
{
  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException
  {

    if (page > 0)
    { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
      return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
    * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
    */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now we perform our rendering */
    g.drawString("Hello world!", 100, 100);

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(DialogTypeSelection.COMMON);
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintable(this);
    boolean ok = job.printDialog(aset);
    if (ok)
    {
      try
      {
        job.print();
      }
      catch (PrinterException ex)
      {
        /* The job did not successfully complete */
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
    printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
    f.add("Center", printButton);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```